# Libraries for rolling your own mobile analytics engine

Tags: android, ios, mobile-analytics

I have a mobile app on both iOS and Android, and a key thing I need to start reliably measuring is the number of users subscribed to certain feeds that they can access within the app. I've tried Google Analytics in the past, creating segments based on an event with the feed URL as the label - but they do such heavy sampling of their events that GA has essentially become a random number generator for me.

I'd like to replace this with my own API on my own server that the app pings, so that it can log the number of users in each group. However, there's a ton of stuff that Google Analytics does out of the box, such as online caching of events until the user has an internet connection and so on, that I really don't want to have to implement from scratch. Does anybody know of any (ideally cross-platform) open source libraries that provide a generic analytics framework where I can just plug in my own API?

Comment: Yes, PIWIK is one of the good analytic tools which we  can establish with our own server

Comment: http://web-analytics.softwareinsider.com/

Comment: @NikunjPatel Thanks - though these feel a bit more like full-on analytics solutions than what I'm after. I just want something on the app side that I can rig up to "ping" my own web-api

Comment: you mean to say that you want to make dash board of analytics at application end and that will not communicate with server ?

Comment: I am exactly not getting you .. kindly elaborate exact what you say

Comment: @NikunjPatel So, I don't care how many people are using my app, I don't want to store gazillions of records in my database - I just want something that will ping my API every time a user performs a specific action, and leave it to my API to decide what to do with that. But with all of the support for e.g. what happens if the user is offline when they perform the action that you get with these full-on analytics solutions